# Proof $y=x^3/(x^2+1)$ is injective

Tags: functions

i need to proof that $$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}$$ is injective

I tried $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and I also tried with Rolle's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\exists a,b:\ f(a)=f(b)$, then \begin{align*}\frac{a^3}{a^2+1}=\frac{b^3}{b^2+1}&\iff a^3b^2+a^3=b^3a^2+b^3 \\ &\iff a^3b^2-a^2b^3+a^3-b^3=0 \\&\iff a^2b^2(a-b)+(a-b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=0 \\ &\iff (a-b)\left[a^2b^2+a^2+ab+b^2\right]=0\\&\iff a=b\vee a^2b^2+a^2+ab+b^2=0\end{align*}

Edit: based on @egreg's comment: $$a^2b^2+a^2+ab+b^2=(ab)^2+\left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3b^2}{4}\ge 0$$ and equality holds if and only if $a=b=0$.

Either way, we found that $a=b$, hence the function is injective.

Comment: $a^2b^2+a^2+ab+b^2=(ab)^2+(a+b/2)^2+3b^2/4$. A sum of squares is nonnegative and is zero if and only if each term is zero.

Comment: @egreg, thanks, I have looked after the factorization, but didn't manage to compute it by myself.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Prove that, for each real $x$, $f'(x)\geqslant0$.

Comment: I did it, but still dont know how it's can help me

Comment: SInce $f'(x)$ is always non-negative, $f$ is invreasing. Now, suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x$ and some $y$ such that $x<y$. Then $f$ is constant in $[x,y]$ and therefore $f'$ is $0$ there. But $f'$ only has one single zero.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach if you want to avoid derivatives. For $x \neq 0$, we have 
$$\frac{x^3}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^3}}.$$

The function $1/x + 1/x^3$ for $x > 0$ is the sum of two strictly decreasing functions, hence itself strictly decreasing and therefore one to one with range $(0, \infty)$. Hence $1/(1/x + 1/x^3)$ is strictly increasing and one to one with range $(0, \infty)$. For $x < 0$, notice $1/x + 1/x^3$ is an odd function, and therefore a similar argument shows $1/(1/x + 1/x^3)$ is one to one with range $(-\infty, 0)$.

In fact, this shows that if you add back the point $x = 0$, the function is a bijection since the function is zero here.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(a)=f(b)$: then
$$
a^3(b^2+1)=b^3(a^2+1)
$$
This implies
$$
a^3b^2-a^2b^3+a^3-b^3=0
$$
and so
$$
a^2b^2(a-b)+(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=0
$$
Conclude.

> If you know that $a^2+ab+b^2\le0$ if and only if $a=b=0$, you're done.

With calculus,
$$
f'(x)=\frac{3x^2(x^2+1)-2x^4}{(x^2+1)^2}
$$
The derivative only vanishes at $0$, so Rolle's theorem would only apply to an interval of the form $[a,b]$, with $a<0$ and $b>0$. Can $f(a)=f(b)$ in this case?